# ¿Cómo mandar una arreglo de objetos con JSON y AJAX en .net MVC?

Tags: ajax, sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero actualizar la asistencia de los alumnos mediante unos checkboxes, y para lograrlo estoy enviando un arreglo de objetos con el método AJAX en formato JSON, al momento de enviar el valor NO recibo ninguna respuesta, pienso que el problema es la forma en que recibo el valor en el parámetro de mi JsonResult.

Los checkboxes lo que hacen es cambiar el valor de los labels en mi página, ya que eso es lo que se mandará y no el valor de los checkboxes.

**Clase Alumno**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FormularioCharlas.Models
{
    public class ClsAlumno
    {
        public string id_alumno { get; set; }
        public string dni_alumno { get; set; }
        public string nombre_alumno { get; set; }
        public string ape_pat_alumno { get; set; }
        public string ape_mat_alumno { get; set; }
        public string asistencia_alumno { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controlador**

```
//ACTUALIZAR ALUMNOS
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ActualizarAlumnos(List<ClsAlumno> array_alumnos_Json)
    {
        foreach (var item in array_alumnos_Json)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ALUMNOS SET ASISTENCIA_ALUMNO =  @ASISTENCIA WHERE ID_ALUMNO = @ID)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ASISTENCIA", item.asistencia_alumno);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", item.id_alumno);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }

        return Json("");

    }
```

**Ajax con Json**

```
//ENVIAR OBJETOS CON AJAX Y JSON

$("#btn-actualizar").on("click", function () {

    //ARREGLO DE OBJETOS
    var array_alumnos = new Array();

    //OBTENER VALORES Y AGREGARLO AL ARREGLO DE OBJETOS

    $(".tr-alumno").each(function (index, element) {
        var lbl_id = $(element).find(".lbl-id").text().trim();
        var lbl_dni = $(element).find(".lbl-dni").text().trim();
        var lbl_nombre = $(element).find(".lbl-nombre").text().trim();
        var lbl_ape_pat = $(element).find(".lbl-ape_pat").text().trim();
        var lbl_ape_mat = $(element).find(".lbl-ape_mat").text().trim();
        var lbl_asistencia = $(element).find(".lbl-asistencia").text().trim();

        array_alumnos.push({ lbl_id, lbl_dni, lbl_nombre, lbl_ape_pat, lbl_ape_mat, lbl_asistencia });
    });

    //ENNVIAR ARREGLO DE OBJETOS AL JSON RESULT ActualizarAlumnos POR MÉTODO POST

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ActualizarAlumnos", "Charlas")',
    data: { array_alumnos_Json: JSON.stringify(array_alumnos) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (rpta) {
        //AQUÍ IRÁ MENSAJE DE ACTUALIZACION DE ASISTENCIA
    },
    error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

**Vista**

```
    @model IEnumerable<FormularioCharlas.Models.ClsAlumno>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id_alumno)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dni_alumno)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombre_alumno)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ape_pat_alumno)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ape_mat_alumno)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.asistencia_alumno)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr class="tr-alumno">
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id_alumno)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-dni">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dni_alumno)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-nombre">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre_alumno)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-ape_pat">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ape_pat_alumno)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-ape_mat">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ape_mat_alumno)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="lbl-asistencia">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.asistencia_alumno)</label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="chk-asistencia" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<input type="submit" id="btn-actualizar" class="btn btn-success"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //CUANDO LOS DATOS SE CARGUEN, EXAMINAREMOS LOS LABELS CON LOS VALORES "ASISTIO" Y  "FALTO",  COLOCAREMOS (CHECKED, true) EN LOS CHECKBOXES SI EL VALOR DEL LABEL ES "ASISTIO"
        //Y (CHECKED, false) SI EL VALOR DEL LABEL ES "FALSO"  

        $(".lbl-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
            if (element.textContent == "ASISTIO") {
                $(element).parent().find(".chk-asistencia").prop("checked", true)
            }
            else {
                $(element).parent().find(".chk-asistencia").prop("checked", false)
            }
        });


        //UN LISTENER QUE CAMBIARÁ EL VALOR DE LOS LABELS SI EL VALOR CAMBIA EN LOS CHECKBOXES

        $(".chk-asistencia").on('change', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).siblings(".lbl-asistencia").text("ASISTIO");
            }
            else {
                $(this).siblings(".lbl-asistencia").text("FALTO");
            }
        });

    });

    //ENVIAR OBJETOS CON AJAX Y JSON

    $("#btn-actualizar").on("click", function () {

        //ARREGLO DE OBJETOS
        var array_alumnos = new Array();

        //OBTENER VALORES Y AGREGARLO AL ARREGLO DE OBJETOS

        $(".tr-alumno").each(function (index, element) {
            var lbl_id = $(element).find(".lbl-id").text().trim();
            var lbl_dni = $(element).find(".lbl-dni").text().trim();
            var lbl_nombre = $(element).find(".lbl-nombre").text().trim();
            var lbl_ape_pat = $(element).find(".lbl-ape_pat").text().trim();
            var lbl_ape_mat = $(element).find(".lbl-ape_mat").text().trim();
            var lbl_asistencia = $(element).find(".lbl-asistencia").text().trim();

            array_alumnos.push({ lbl_id, lbl_dni, lbl_nombre, lbl_ape_pat, lbl_ape_mat, lbl_asistencia });
        });

        //ENNVIAR ARREGLO DE OBJETOS AL JSON RESULT ActualizarAlumnos POR MÉTODO POST

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ActualizarAlumnos", "Charlas")',
        data: { array_alumnos_Json: JSON.stringify(array_alumnos) },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (rpta) {
            //AQUÍ IRÁ MENSAJE DE ACTUALIZACION DE ASISTENCIA
        },
        error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });



</script>
```

**Mi tabla Alumnos**

```
    CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS
(
ID_ALUMNO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
DNI_ALUMNO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
NOMBRE_ALUMNO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
APE_PAT_ALUMNO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
APE_MAT_ALUMNO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ASISTENCIA_ALUMNO VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'FALTO' NULL
);
```

**Los registros que contiene la tabla Alumnos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La página**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para que el Data binding funcione en el controlador los nombres de los parámetros que se envían deben tener el mismo nombre que las propiedades del objeto a las que se quiere mapear.

Si en tu clase `ClsAlumno` tienes la propiead `id_alumno` entonces el json debe tener una propiedad con el mismo nombre (id_alumno) y no `lbl_id` como lo estás enviando.

**Actualización**

Estuve haciendo pruebas y para que los datos que envías sean mapeados correctamente debes cambiar dos cosas:

1. Envía los datos por medio de POST y no GET, cambia eso en la petición ajax y en el controlador.
2. No conviertas el objeto JSON a string con JSON.stringify(). Solo envíalo tal cual está.

Comment: Hola @crrlos, acabo de cambiar el nombre de las propiedades como me dijiste pero aún no sigo teniendo exito. Coloque un mensaje para ver si esta funcionando bien el método ajax y HAY RESULTADOS, pero lo que quiero es que se actualice la columna asistencia de mi tabla alumnos.